# Instance variable inheritance problems

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, instance

For some unknown reason my program seems to be creating an instance of the character but not assigning an `_id` even though the `_id` even has a default in the `__init__`.
I'm not sure why this is and yes I'm new to python and trying to learn OOP and inheritance to make sure I fully understood the tutorials I had watched I decided to create a kind of complex program for this.

```
class Entity(object):
    def __init__(self, _id = None):
        self._id = _id
        self._pos = (0, 0)
        self._vel = (0, 0)

# --------------------------------------------------------------

class Character(Entity):
    def __init__(self, _id = None, _name = None):
        self._id, self._name = _id, _name
        self._entity = Entity.__init__(self._id)

# --------------------------------------------------------------

character = Character(0, 'End')
```

The error's I get is as follow's...

```
File "test.py", line 119, in <module>
    character = Character(0, 'End')
File "test.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._entity = Entity.__init__(self._id)
File "test.py", line 5, in __init__
    self._id = _id

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_id'
```

I think this means that when a new object of Character/Entity is created it cannot find, init or define the `_id` variable? This is probably a simple error and I'm doing something very wrong but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the super-class incorrectly. You must pass `self` in as well:

```
self._entity = Entity.__init__(self, self._id)
```

However, it is easier to use `super()` in most cases:

```
self._entity = super().__init__(self._id)
```

In both cases:

```
character = Character(0, 'End')
print(vars(character))
# {'_id': 0, '_name': 'End', '_pos': (0, 0), '_vel': (0, 0), '_entity': None}
```

Also, it is pointless to assign the return value of the init (always `None`) to `self._entity`. You can just make it

```
Entity.__init__(self, self._id)
```

or

```
super().__init__(self._id)
```

Comment: Also, probably best to remove the assignment to `self._entity`. It's just going to be None anyway.

Comment: That helped alot thankyou however im still uncertain about something the whole `self._entity` var always being `None` that was an attempt to create a var that refers to the `Entity` object of that instance but since you said it's pointless I guess there is some built in way to refer to the inherited values of a instance of a class?

Comment: @End As you have already inherited from Entity class, it properties will be available in Character class using *self*. If you want to access _id from Entity in character class methods just write self._id.

Comment: @Avij ah i see thank's so the `Character class` has a `_id` variable but so does the `Entity class` so if i call `self._id` which one is called the one from `Character` or the one from `Entity`? would i instead call `Entity._id` or maybe `self.Entity._id`?